# create variables with different names with the length of a digit

Tags: python

So for example `num = 1010`, so `num` is 4 digits long, can you create 4 variables automatic?

for example:

```
num = 1010
len(num)

num_2 = whatever
num_3 = whatever
num_4 = whatever
num_5 = whatever
```

because `num` got 4 digits, you add 4 extra variables (doesn't matter which name)
so if `num` would be 5 digits, you had num_2 - num_6 (so its 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) and so on..
so if there are more digits, it creates automatic new variables (or less digits, less variables)

because to write it with if it would take long, to create when num could be 1 but also 1000 (with input() )

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? why add a variable number of variables?

Comment: Just store the data in a dictionary.

Comment: You could use a dict with n number of keys, if you just want to use as data storage

Comment: Are you wanting to end up with a collection of ordered variables each with one digit of the starting number?

Comment: You can use a simple list. `data = [0] * len(str(num))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 2):

Use dictionary instead of multiple variables with almost like same name

```py
num = 1010
length = len(str(num))

res = {i+1:str(num)[i-1] for i in range(1, length+1)}
res[1] = num
```

This gives a better and easy way to access variables

And the `num[1]` is to store the original value of the `num` variable, you can remove it if you don't need

Your required values will be stored in the `res` dictionary

If you want to use the `num` name to access values like `num_` which you are familiar with (i guess) then change res to num

```py
num = res
```

And access the first digit of `1010` (here, 1) like `num[2]`

Or you can also use a simple list to store them like

```py
res = [num, *[i for i in iter(str(num))]]
```

Here, your required variable values will be in the `res` list

Or if you still want the `num_`format variables, then

```py
for i in range(2, len(str(num))+2):
    globals()[f'num_{i}'] = str(num)[i-2]
```

The values will get stored in the variables named like `num_2`, `num_3`, `num_4`, ...

One-line for the same above code

```py
globals().update({f'num_{i}': str(num)[i-2] for i in range(2, len(str(num))+2)})
```

Tell me if its not working for you...

Comment: Seems like the code probably doesnt really help... maybe I just didn't said it good enough, so if num had 4 digits (for example 1010) can you add 4 variables, that go from num_2 to num_5 (so its "num_" with a number from 2, 3, 4, 5 (for the digits)), so if num would be 5 digits for example then it would go from num_2 to num_6 ("num_" + 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).

Comment: @Chaos i edited my answer, tell me if its okay for you...

Comment: @Chaos is it okay now chaos? i saw some notifications tho...

Comment: ye worked, tyvm